# How should I design MongoDB User Schema for Ecommerce website?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have designed the User Schema, but I am a bit confused about the User Shipping Address. The user might have many shipping addresses that he wants to save in his profile.

So I am a bit confused whether I should create a separate Address schema and refer the User inside or save the Array of the Address object directly in the User Schema. But, one problem I have noticed; If I save the address in the Address Array under User's Schema, I will not have an object ID for the Address to be identified that which address I want to get. In this situation, I will have to face the problem to update the address.

If someone can tell me how should I go, It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an object ID to do that task.

The solution is that you can just manually assign an id to each address 
by just putting both id and address in a json document and then pushing it in the array of addresses.

it will look something like this after in json format

---

```
address : [
{ 
   id:1,
   address:"address 1"
},
{
  id:2,
  address:"address 2"
}
]
```